# Why does text doesn't gets a height of 0px?

Tags: html, css, web, paragraph

I was trying to make a webpage using css .. Suddenly i realized that i could not set the height of some text in paragraph(or div) to 0px. I thought of getting some help from this amazing community.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
p{
background-color:red;
height:0px;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>All behold the power of mighty Juggernaut</p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the question (currently) proposed; that question is asking how to apply a height of 0 to the parent `<div>`, this question is asking how to set a `font-size` of 0 to the text of an element. Given that I'm biased, having answered the question, I'm not voting to reopen, but I genuinely believe it was wrongly closed.

Answer (score -1):

Use font-size instead,it will make it 0 px if is set to 0

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    p{
    background-color:red;
    
font-size:0px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <p>All behold the power of mighty Juggernaut</p>


    </body>

    </html>
```